# Cloudformation Template validator

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to include a custom validator in the CFN template?

I know we can add rule enforcement like this:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/how-to-perform-cross-parameter-validation-using-aws-cloudformation-rules-and-assertions/

However, the supported function is really limited. I am looking for a way to measure the length of a string parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [cfn-lint](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint) to validate your templates, you can add custom validation rules (including `StringMax` for string length validations) as explained [here](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/blob/master/docs/customize_specifications.md).

Answer (score 0):

[CloudFormation parameters also support constraints like `MinLength` and `MaxLength`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#parameters-section-structure-properties)